# rails internationalization apostrophe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, apostrophe

I have a file config/locales/events.en.yml:

```
en:
  im_going: im going
```

And I would like it to be

```
en:
  im_going: i'm going
```

But when I do this I get several errors in random parts of code. Does anybody know how to internationalizate a string with apostrophe?

Thanks in advance, alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those little things that have always annoyed me about YML.  Anyway, quote your string and everything should be okay:

```
en:
  im_going: "i'm going"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This only works with me if I then output the translation as `raw`. Is this always necessary for any any special symbols?

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2534365

```
en:
  im_going: 'i''m going'
```